# Running a Google survey through an online panel

Tags: google-forms

I will be conducting a survey through an online third-party panel and need to upload my Google survey link but they require a unique ID tag for them to be able to identify unique responses. Do you know if adding this `ID=[ID]` to the end of the form would work?

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1_qXpCl8NixvDnLKrcf2eECoKYCEjwbDz_njGOl0Wt6w/viewform?ID=[ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, you can pre-populate a Google form using URL parameters. Google has some help around this: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/160000?hl=en

To be clear, you are not using "Google survey" which sounds like the separate and distinct service (Google Consumer Surveys) which provides survey sampling in partnership with online news sites by intercepting users and asking them to complete a survey in order to read a news article.